# Does Robot Framework automatically import current directory where your robot test is located?

Tags: robotframework

Does Robot automatically import directories(current and sub directory) where you run your robot file? If yes, is there a way to avoid that?

e.g. mytest.robot current dir is /home/test/mytest.robot, after running mytest.robot, PYTHONPATH includes /home/test/

Comment: Are you asking about automatically importing files, or setting the PATH where files are imported from?

Comment: Automatically importing files. I noticed this on debian 9 where I run my robot scripts. At the start it imports the libraries included in $PATH and $PYTHONPATH right? But I've noticed that the directory where the robot file is found, was also imported. Which is quite weird for me.

Comment: _" At the start it imports the libraries included in $PATH and $PYTHONPATH right?"_ - no, it won't import anything unless you tell it to (other than the libraries that come with robotframework).

Answer (score 0):

> Does Robot automatically import directories(current and sub directory) where you run your robot file?

No, the only thing it automatically imports are the built-in keywords. Robot will not set PYTHONPATH unless you tell it to.

Comment: I don't think it was really added in PYTHONPATH. It's just that during the start of a robot run, libraries such as $PATH and $PYTHONPATH are imported first. But I noticed that the directory where the robot file is located was also imported.

Comment: @Octane: I can't make sense of your comment. $PATH and $PYTHONPATH are not libraries, they are environment variables. Robot doesn't automatically import anything except its own built-in libraries.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the [documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-pythonpath-option) below,

> The BuiltIn [library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-pythonpath-option) is special because it is taken into use
>   automatically and thus **its keywords are always available**.

Although, RF documentation does not mention anything on loading directories automatically, according to robot run [documentation](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.html#module-robot.run), and the actual test [robot code](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/atest/resources/atest_resource.robot), they are testing with and without pythonpath argument.

robot would start the execution of the test file by loading the file and keeping the loaded file path in PYTHONPATH (even for this to happen, they are making use of --PYTHONPATH), that is the reason you are seeing dir.

> excerpt code from robot framework code repo mentioned below,

```
${RUNNER DEFAULTS}
...               ${COMMON DEFAULTS}
...               --ConsoleMarkers OFF
...               --PYTHONPATH "${CURDIR}${/}..${/}testresources${/}testlibs"
...               --PYTHONPATH "${CURDIR}${/}..${/}testresources${/}listeners"

*** Keywords ***
Run Tests
    [Arguments]    ${options}=    ${sources}=    ${default options}=${RUNNER DEFAULTS}    ${output}=${OUTFILE}
    [Documentation]    *OUTDIR:* file://${OUTDIR} (regenerated for every run)
    ${result} =    Execute    ${INTERPRETER.runner}   ${options}    ${sources}    ${default options}
    Log Many    RC: ${result.rc}    STDERR:\n${result.stderr}    STDOUT:\n${result.stdout}
    Process Output    ${output}
    [Return]    ${result}
```

> Does Robot automatically import directories(current and sub directory)
>   where you run your robot file? If yes, is there a way to avoid that?

Even according to the code, the answer is "no". as far as changing this behavior, you can always make use of --pythonpath option.